# Step option is not fired in toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I was trying to create a sliding menu, using toggle() method but needed to call a function (that was interacting with div height) while sliding into view. for this, I've used the step option (as seen in documentation) to call this function has soon has sliding starts to occur. I did many tests, and it seems that this option is not working with toggle().

I've tried to use animate() with the same call and its working perfectly...?

I've made a simple fiddle here ( [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fled/cVP7J/2/) ) to illustrate the problem.

I've tried it in the last version of IE and Chrome with version 1.11.0 of jQuery

```
// This is for toggle method
$(document).on("click", "#toggle", function(){
  $("#menu").toggle({effect: "slide", direction: "left", width: "show", step: function(){
      if ($("#menu").hasClass("open")){       //***** THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
        $("#menu").removeClass("open");  
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      } else{
        $("#menu").addClass("open");  
        $("#menu").css("background-color", "green");
      }
    }
  }) ;       
});
```

Comment: So in each step `#menu` has or removes class `open`. Obviously till the end of animation the final step removes `open` class

Comment: I know that this is not an obvious way to use this step functionality but this code was just trown their to demonstrate that it was not called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the fiddle is not correctly enclosed in parens (step is in another couple of {}); so the option are not passed correctly to the toggle function.

Code:

```
// This is for toggle method
$(document).on("click", "#toggle", function(){
  $("#menu").toggle({effect: "slide", direction: "left", width: "show", step: function(){
      if ($("#menu").hasClass("open")){       //***** THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
        $("#menu").removeClass("open");  
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      } else{
        $("#menu").addClass("open");  
        $("#menu").css("background-color", "green");
      }
    }
  }) ;       
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/QzyEU/

Comment: I have used your correction on my code and its working perfectly in a stand alone page, thanks.
  
The reason I had published this question is because I need the same behavior in a bigger project (I need to display a FAQ page using toggle from (right to left), with the use of step functionality to resize the height of a div in regards to its parent...

As I said, your code is working perfectly in a stand alone page but when I copy paste this code into my bigger project (using the same jquery version), the step functionality is not executed.

Could anybody give some advices for my investigation